# Como posso criar uma SeekBar

Tags: android, áudio

Quero criar uma barra que  mostra a reprodução da musica. Criei uma SeekBar apra que quando o audio começa a reproduzir mostre o seu tempo de duranção e quanto tempo passou depois de o iniciar ...

```
SeekBar myseekbar;
myseekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.myseekbar);
myseekbar.setMax(mp1.getDuration());
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
            myseekbar.setProgress(mp1.getCurrentPosition());
      }
},0,1000);
```

Utilizei esse codigo mas nao da
Como posso fazer para chegar a esse fim.

Comment: Voce tem que pegar o tempo executado do Media player e passar pro SeekBar

Comment: e como eu faço para o pegar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse exemplo esta usando Android Annotation.
Esta é a activity de um player de um aplicativo de Podcast

```
package br.com.podcast.podcast.view;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.squareup.picasso.Transformation;

import org.androidannotations.annotations.AfterViews;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.Click;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.Extra;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.OptionsItem;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.ViewById;

import br.com.podcast.podcast.R;
import br.com.podcast.podcast.domain.Episodio;
import br.com.podcast.podcast.domain.Podcast;
import br.com.podcast.podcast.service.background.player.PlayerBinder;
import br.com.podcast.podcast.service.background.player.PlayerCallBack;
import br.com.podcast.podcast.service.background.player.PlayerService;
import br.com.podcast.podcast.service.background.player.PlayerService_;
import br.com.podcast.podcast.util.DateUtils;
import br.com.podcast.podcast.util.InternetUtil;
import br.com.podcast.podcast.util.Load;
import jp.wasabeef.picasso.transformations.BlurTransformation;
import jp.wasabeef.picasso.transformations.ColorFilterTransformation;

import static android.os.Build.VERSION;
import static android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES;

@EActivity(R.layout.activity_player)
public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ServiceConnection, PlayerCallBack {
    private PlayerService playerService;
    private boolean connected = false;
    private Load load;

    @ViewById
    ImageView background;
    @ViewById
    TextView title;
    @ViewById
    ImageView logo;
    @ViewById
    TextView progressTime;
    @ViewById
    TextView duration;
    @ViewById
    SeekBar progressBar;
    @ViewById
    ImageView playPause;
    @ViewById
    TextView titleEpisodio;
    @ViewById
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Extra
    Podcast podcast;
    @Extra
    Integer selectedPodcast;
    @Extra
    Boolean autoPlay;

    @AfterViews
    void afterViewPlayerActivity(){
        PlayerService_.intent(getApplication()).start();
        doBindService();
        load = new Load(this, Load.Color.DARK);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        load.show();
    }

    private void init(){
        playPause.setSelected(true);
        resetSeekBar();
        title.setText(podcast.getNome());

        //Imagem do album
        int size = (InternetUtil.screenWidth(this) / 5) * 4;
        Picasso.with(this).load(podcast.getImage()).resize(size,size).placeholder(R.drawable.holder_quad).into(logo);

        //Imagem de fundo
        Transformation blur = new BlurTransformation(this, 12, 4);
        Transformation filterColor = new ColorFilterTransformation(Color.argb(130, 0, 0, 0));
        Picasso.with(this).load(podcast.getImage()).transform(blur).transform(filterColor).into(background);

        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLACK);
        }

        playerService.setPodcast(podcast, selectedPodcast, autoPlay);
    }

    private void resetSeekBar(){
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setSecondaryProgress(0);
        progressTime.setText("00:00");
        duration.setText("00:00");
    }

    //Clicks Controll

    @Click
    void back(){
        if(connected){
            playerService.playPreview();
        }
    }

    @Click
    void back30(){
        if(connected) {
            int newPosition = playerService.getPosition() - (30 * 1000);
            if(newPosition < 0 ){
                playerService.seekTo(0);
                onProgress(0);
            }else{
                playerService.seekTo(newPosition); //30 segundos
                onProgress(newPosition);
            }
        }
    }

    @Click
    void playPause(){
        if(connected) {
            if (playerService.isPlaying()) {
                playerService.pause();
            } else {
                playerService.play();
            }
            playPause.setSelected(!playerService.isPlaying());
        }
    }

    @Click
    void nex30(){
        if(connected){
            int newPosition = playerService.getPosition() + (30 * 1000);

            if(newPosition > playerService.getDuration()){
                playerService.playNext();
                onProgress(playerService.getDuration());
            }else{
                playerService.seekTo(newPosition); //30 segundos
                onProgress(newPosition);
            }
        }
    }

    @Click
    void next(){
        if(connected){
            playerService.playNext();
        }
    }

    //Listeners player

    @Override
    public void onProgress(int progress) {
        progressBar.setProgress(progress);
        progressTime.setText(DateUtils.toClockTimestampInSecondsFormat(playerService.getPosition()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepare(Episodio episodio) {
        load.hide();
        progressBar.setMax(playerService.getDuration());
        duration.setText(DateUtils.toClockTimestampInSecondsFormat(playerService.getDuration()));
        progressBar.setProgress(playerService.getPosition());
        progressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (connected) {
                    progressTime.setText(DateUtils.toClockTimestampInSecondsFormat(progress));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                playerService.stopProgressUpdate();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                if (connected) {
                    playerService.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
                    playerService.startProgressUpdate();
                }
            }
        });
        progressTime.setText(DateUtils.toClockTimestampInSecondsFormat(playerService.getPosition()));
        playPause.setSelected(!playerService.isPlaying());
        titleEpisodio.setText(episodio.getTitulo());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayer() {
        playPause.setSelected(!playerService.isPlaying());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause_() {
        playPause.setSelected(!playerService.isPlaying());
    }

    @Override
    public void onEpisodioChange(Episodio episodio) {
        titleEpisodio.setText(episodio.getTitulo());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String message) {
        load.hide();
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferInit() {
        load.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferFinish() {
        load.hide();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferUpdate(int percent) {
        progressBar.setSecondaryProgress((int)(playerService.getDuration() * (percent / 100.0)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder binder) {
        playerService = ((PlayerBinder) binder).getService();
        playerService.setPlayerCallBack(this);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        playerService = null;
        connected = false;
    }

    private void doBindService(){
        try{
            if(!connected){
                bindService(PlayerService_.intent(getApplication()).get(), this, 0);
                connected = true;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void doUnbindService(){
        try{
            if(connected){
                unbindService(this);
                connected = false;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        doUnbindService();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @OptionsItem(android.R.id.home)
    void homeSelected() {
        finish();
    }
}
}
```

Esta Classe é um Service que sera nosso PlayerService. O service garante que o audio vai continuar sendo executado mesmo que a aplicação seja colocada em segundo plano.

```
package br.com.podcast.podcast.service.background.player;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PowerManager;

import org.androidannotations.annotations.EService;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import br.com.podcast.podcast.domain.Podcast;
import br.com.podcast.podcast.domain.helper.FinishGeneralEventBusHelper;
import br.com.podcast.podcast.domain.helper.PlayerCommandEventBusHelper;
import br.com.podcast.podcast.domain.helper.PlayerStatusEventBusHelper;
import lombok.Setter;

@EService
public class PlayerService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,
        CallbackEventsCallAndPhone, MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener, RemoteControlListener {
    private final IBinder playerBinder = new PlayerBinder(this);
    private MediaPlayer player;
    private int currentPosition = 0;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private boolean isMyPause = false;
    private final Runnable callBackRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(player.isPlaying() && playerCallBack != null)
                playerCallBack.onProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());
        }
    };
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    private ScheduledFuture<?> callBackHandle;
    private RemoteControlNotification remoteControlNotification;
    private Podcast podcast;

    @Setter
    private PlayerCallBack playerCallBack;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        initPlayer();
        PlayerIntentReceiver.getInstance(this, getApplicationContext()).register();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        remoteControlNotification = RemoteControlNotification.getInstance(this, this);
        remoteControlNotification.register();
    }

    private void initPlayer() {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
        player.setOnInfoListener(this);
        player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return playerBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent){
        playerCallBack = null;
        stopProgressUpdate();
        return false;
    }

    public void startProgressUpdate() {
        if(player.isPlaying() && playerCallBack != null){
            if (!scheduler.isShutdown())
                callBackHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        handler.post(callBackRunnable);
                    }
                }, 500, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }

    public void stopProgressUpdate(){
        if(callBackHandle != null)
            callBackHandle.cancel(false);
    }

    public void stopService(){
        stopSelf();
    }

    public void setPodcast(Podcast podcast, Integer selectedPosition, Boolean autoPlay){
        if(this.podcast != null) {
            if(podcast.getUrl().equals(this.podcast.getUrl())){
                if(isPlaying()){
                    if(selectedPosition != null && selectedPosition >= 0 ){
                        pause();
                        jumpTo(selectedPosition);
                    }
                    playerCallBack.onPrepare(this.podcast.getEpisodios().get(currentPosition));
                }else{
                    if(selectedPosition != null && selectedPosition >= 0 )
                        currentPosition = selectedPosition;

                    if(autoPlay != null && autoPlay)
                        play();

                    playerCallBack.onPrepare(this.podcast.getEpisodios().get(currentPosition));
                }
            }else{
                this.podcast = podcast;
                if(isPlaying()) {
                    pause();
                }
                currentPosition = 0;
                resetPlayer();
            }
        }else{
            this.podcast = podcast;
            if(selectedPosition != null && selectedPosition >= 0 )
                currentPosition = selectedPosition;
            resetPlayer();
        }
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onCommand(final PlayerCommandEventBusHelper helper){
        switch (helper.command){
            case NEXT:
                playNext();
                break;
            case PAUSE:
                pause();
                break;
            case PlAYER:
                play();
                break;
            case PREVIEW:
                playPreview();
                break;
            case STOP:
                stopPodcast();
                break;
            case STATUS_REQUEST:
                break;
        }

        EventBus.getDefault().post(getStatus());
    }

    private PlayerStatusEventBusHelper getStatus(){
        PlayerStatusEventBusHelper helper = new PlayerStatusEventBusHelper();
        helper.podcast = podcast;
        helper.episodioCorrente = currentPosition;

        if(isPlaying()) {
            helper.status = PlayerStatusEventBusHelper.Status.PLAYING;
        }else {
            if (podcast != null)
                helper.status = PlayerStatusEventBusHelper.Status.PAUSED;
            else
                helper.status = PlayerStatusEventBusHelper.Status.STOPED;
        }

        return helper;
    }

    public void stopPodcast(){
        stop();
        podcast = null;
        currentPosition = 0;
        initPlayer();
    }

    //Comandos da notificação

    @Override
    public void onPlay() {
       play();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext30() {
        int newPosition = getPosition() - (30 * 1000);
        if(newPosition < 0 ){
            seekTo(0);
            if(playerCallBack != null)
                playerCallBack.onProgress(0);
        }else{
            seekTo(newPosition); //30 segundos
            if(playerCallBack != null)
                playerCallBack.onProgress(newPosition);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreview30() {
        int newPosition = getPosition() + (30 * 1000);

        if(newPosition > getDuration()){
            playNext();
            if(playerCallBack != null)
                playerCallBack.onProgress(getDuration());
        }else{
            seekTo(newPosition); //30 segundos
            if(playerCallBack != null)
                playerCallBack.onProgress(newPosition);
        }
    }

    //Commandos do Player

    public void resetPlayer(){
        try{
            if(player.isLooping())
                player.stop();

            player.release();
            initPlayer();

            if(playerCallBack != null)
                playerCallBack.onEpisodioChange(podcast.getEpisodios().get(currentPosition));

            player.setDataSource(podcast.getEpisodios().get(currentPosition).getUrl());
            player.prepareAsync();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            playerCallBack.onError("Erro ao chamar o servidor de podcast");
        }

        remoteControlNotification.playNotification(podcast, currentPosition);
    }

    public void playNext(){
        stopProgressUpdate();

        currentPosition++;
        if(currentPosition >= podcast.getEpisodios().size())
            currentPosition = 0;

        resetPlayer();
    }

    public void play(){
        if(!player.isPlaying())
            player.start();

        if(playerCallBack != null){
            playerCallBack.onEpisodioChange(podcast.getEpisodios().get(currentPosition));
            playerCallBack.onPlayer();
            startProgressUpdate();
        }

        remoteControlNotification.playNotification(podcast, currentPosition);
    }

    public void pause(){
        if(player.isPlaying())
            player.pause();

        if(playerCallBack != null)
            playerCallBack.onPause_();

        stopProgressUpdate();

        remoteControlNotification.pauseNotification(podcast, currentPosition);
    }

    public void seekTo(int position){
        player.seekTo(position);
    }

    public void jumpTo(int position){
        pause();
        currentPosition = position;
        resetPlayer();
    }

    public void playPreview(){
        stopProgressUpdate();

        currentPosition--;
        if(currentPosition < 0)
            currentPosition = podcast.getEpisodios().size() - 1;

        resetPlayer();
    }

    public void stop(){
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        stopProgressUpdate();

        remoteControlNotification.stopNotification();
    }

    public boolean isPlaying(){
        try{
            return player.isPlaying();
        }catch (IllegalStateException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }

    public int getDuration(){
        return player.getDuration();
    }

    public int getPosition(){
        return player.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    //CallBacks

    @Override
    public void onPhoneOut() {
        pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCalling() {
        if(player.isPlaying()){
            isMyPause = true;
            pause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallStart() {
        if(player.isPlaying()){
            isMyPause = true;
            pause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallFinish() {
        if(isMyPause){
            isMyPause = false;
            play();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int percent) {
        if(playerCallBack != null)
            playerCallBack.onBufferUpdate(percent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        stopProgressUpdate();

        if(player.getCurrentPosition() > 0){
            playNext();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        switch (what){
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
                playerCallBack.onError("Erro no servidor");
                System.out.println("Erro no servidor");
                return true;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
                playerCallBack.onError("Servidor do Podcast encontra se fora do ar");
                System.out.println("Servidor do Podcast encontra se fora do ar");
                return true;
        }

        switch (extra){
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_IO:
                playerCallBack.onError("Existe um problema na rede ou no Servidor do podcast");
                System.out.println("Existe um problema na rede ou no Servidor do podcast");
                return true;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_MALFORMED:
                playerCallBack.onError("Este podcast esta com audio corrompido");
                System.out.println("Este podcast esta com audio corrompido");
                return true;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED:
                playerCallBack.onError("Erro no servidor");
                System.out.println("Erro no servidor");
                return true;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_TIMED_OUT:
                playerCallBack.onError("Servidor de podcast temporariamente indisponível");
                System.out.println("Servidor de podcast temporariamente indisponível");
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        switch (what) {
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START:
                if(playerCallBack != null)
                    playerCallBack.onBufferInit();
                pause();
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END:
                if(playerCallBack != null)
                    playerCallBack.onBufferFinish();
                play();
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        if(playerCallBack != null)
            playerCallBack.onPrepare(this.podcast.getEpisodios().get(currentPosition));

        play();
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onFinishAplication(FinishGeneralEventBusHelper helper){
        stop();
        onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        PlayerIntentReceiver.getInstance(this, getApplicationContext()).unregister();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        remoteControlNotification.stopNotification();
        remoteControlNotification.unregister();
        stopForeground(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ignore o código que esta sobrando. Tem partes referente a notificação, remoção do fone, atender ligação no meio do podcast e etc. Tem diversos tratamentos que tem que ser considerados.